# How to change url(name of the document file requested)l using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

How to change url(name of the document file requested)l using htaccess
I want to accomplish this one:

www.mydomain.com/page.html?id=12

to

www.mydomain.com/my

Answer (score 0):

You can put this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.html\?id=12[\s&] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /my? [R=302,L]
```